# Should the JMSMessageID change between publish and subscribe?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

The JMS 2.0 specification says

> The `JMSMessageID` header field contains a value that uniquely
>   identifies each message sent by a provider.

...and...

> The exact scope of uniqueness is provider defined. It should at least
>   cover all messages for a specific installation of a provider where an
>   installation is some connected set of message routers.

The specification does not explicitly state that the `JMSMessageID` returned from the publish API call must match the one present in the message when it is consumed.  The discussion in the spec about moving the `JMSMessageID` to the `JMSCorrelationID` when replying to a request implies that the two would be the same.  If the message ID was changed between publication and consumption, this style of request/reply would fail.

Certainly in the unified domain model of JMS 1.1 and now 2.0, it would not make sense for the behavior of the `JMSMessageID` to change depending on whether the destination is a queue or a topic.  Under the unified model, one would expect all destinations to act alike in this regard.

Also, if "provider" as used in the first paragraph refers to the thing that is sending messages, then a publication that fanned out to 10 identical messages, with identical `JMSMessageID` values, would meet the spec since uniqueness is measured at the sending side.

Unfortunately, the specification liberally switches between using the term "provider" to describe the thing sending messages versus using it to describe the vendor of the JMS transport.  This is evident in the two quoted passages above. This ambiguity doesn't help matters any.

At least one implementation (IBM's MQ) takes the approach that a publication fanning out to 10 messages has created 10 unique, new messages, and therefore each of these has a unique `JMSMessageID` value.  This is arguably consistent with the second quoted passage which requires uniqueness scoped to the provider, where "provider" appears to refer to the vendor implementation and *not* the thing sending messages.

It is my belief that when a published message fans out to multiple subscribers the correct behavior would be that the `JMSMessageID` would be preserved in each instance of the message so that replies can be correlated as expected.  In other words, I believe IBM's implementation to be non-compliant.  Since the specification is ambiguous on the matter, I'm looking for an authoritative source which either states outright or strongly implies the behavior as intended by the spec, one way or the other.  Depending on the response, I'll either stand down, or else raise the issue with IBM as a compliance defect.

Comment: A customer asked me a similar question. They are moving from P2P to Pub/Sub messaging pattern. Their sender application caches message ids for later reconciliation. When using P2P, their sender application rightly gets unique message ids from MQMD. But switching Pub/Sub, message ids become zero and they can't use such message ids.

Comment: Good luck in finding an authoritative source beyond what is written in the spec! Seriously, I mean that, I wish you luck in finding such a source, we probably have lots of questions to ask them once found.

Comment: I did ping Nigel Deakin @JMS_Spec on Twitter with a link to this question. That's as authoritative as it gets but failing a reply from him I thought there might be something in the WebLogic or AQ docs alluding to the correct behavior.  It's something IBM should address regardless, though. The spec discusses request/reply in a way that requires preservation of the ID and it seems pretty clear what the intent is.  What MQ does breaks that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term "provider" here is simply a reference to the specific messaging product being used, and covers both client-side and server-side components. To avoid confusion, I'll use the word JMS product vendor here.

The purpose of the JMS specification is to define a Java API implemented by that messaging product. It uses loose terms like "provider" because the JMS spec does not define how the product is architected and is trying to avoid suggesting how the implementation should be shared between client-side and server-side components, or even whether there is a server (or cluster of servers) at all. You'll notice the spec never (well, almost never) says "the server does this" or "the server does that".

The sentence about the "exact scope of uniqueness" is there to make it easy for the JMS product vendor to implement the code that generates `JMSMessageID` values. It's saying that the code that generates `JMSMessageID` values doesn't need to worry about ensuring that the values generated are unique across the entire universe. It's sufficient to ensure that they are unique to that particular product installation.

You say that "The specification does not explicitly state that the `JMSMessageID` returned from the publish API call must match the one present in the message when it is consumed."

I think this is stated in Section 4.4.11 "How message header values are set". This states that the `JMSMessageID` is set by the "JMS provider send method". The same section goes on to say that "Message header fields that are defined as being set by the 'JMS provider send method' will be available on the sending client as well as on the receiving client."

This means that after the call to send() or publish() has returned, the sending application can use the method `getJMSMessageID()` to find the message ID that was assigned to that message. When this message is received, the receiving application can use the same method, and get the same value.

Each message sent to a topic is delivered to every subscriber on that topic. These subscribers will receive a separate copy of the same message, with the same body, properties and headers, including `JMSMessageID` value.

Feel free to argue; the JMS spec is not free of ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel!  I will leave any arguing to IBM since this is the answer I was expecting.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is less about when the JMSMessageID field is set on a published message, and more about what happens to that message when it is processed within the JMS provider.

As stated in T.Rob's and Nigel's posts, section 3.4.3 of the JMS 2.0 specification states:

> "The JMSMessageID header field contains a value that uniquely
>   identifies each message sent by a provider."

and also:

> "A JMSMessageID is a String value which should function as a unique
>   key for identifying messages in a historical repository. The exact
>   scope of uniqueness is provider defined. It should at least cover all
>   messages for a specific installation of a provider where an
>   installation is some connected set of message routers."

That is to say, two or more messages, even if they contain the same data, ought to have different JMSMessageID values if they constitute different messages within a repository.

The spec also states, in section 4.2.1 that,

> "A topic can be thought of as a mini message broker that gathers and
>   distributes messages addressed to it. By relying on the topic as an
>   intermediary, message publishers are kept independent of subscribers
>   and vice versa."

This would imply that the intention of the spec is that, when a message is sent to a Topic, the Topic can do some work on the message, including creating multiple copies of the message (or, more specifically, creating multiple messages with the same data that are considered separate within the provider's repository.

Finally, section 4.2.2 states:

> "A subscription will receive a copy of every message that is sent to
>   the topic after the subscription is created, ... Each copy of the
>   message is treated as a completely separate message. Work done on one
>   copy has no effect on any other; acknowledging one does not
>   acknowledge any other; one message may be delivered immediately, while
>   another waits for its consumer to process messages ahead of it."

Putting these passages together, the spec can be read as saying

1. When a message is sent to a Topic, that Topic can create a copy of the message for each current subscription.
2. The copies of the message created when sending to a Topic can be considered as completely separate messages.
3. Because separate JMS messages are uniquely identified by their JMSMessageID field, each separate subscription message should have a different JMSMessageID

To pick up Nigel's last sentence the JMS specification isn't free of ambiguities. This is very true and vendors and customers have previously worked around issues, and work in the expert group does take place to clarify these and provide guidance as well as make suggestions for improving the compliance tests. Based on the understanding outlined above, and the tests within the JMS 2.0 Compliance Test Suite that IBM MQ v8 passes, the IBM MQ v8 implementation is JMS2.0 compliant (and likewise earlier IBM MQ versions are JMS1.1 compliant; the JMS 1.1 specification has the same ambiguity).

The request-response paradigm is a common one, though with a pub-sub based distribution model the sending application does potentially have to cope with multiple responses not just the one that would be more likely with a point-point architecture.  We acknowledge that there are messaging scenarios where the capability for a message id to have a different 'value of uniqueness' from the one currently implemented by IBM MQ would provide value to some IBM MQ customers

For the above reasons IBM strongly believes that its MQ JMS solution is compliant, so a PMR will not be accepted. However, *we do acknowledge* that there are a number of use cases where maintaining the message ID would be beneficial to you. For that reason we will make [RFE 35062](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=35062) an uncommitted candidate, which means it has the highest probability of being addressed and we promise that we're actively working to provide the solution that best fits the needs as quickly as possible. But to do this we'd appreciate additional feedback on the RFE with descriptions of what the actual problems our users are trying to solve here. For example is this for audit purposes, request-reply, message flows, etc, and what it is you need replicated? The more information we have, the more likely the solution is to satisfy the need.

Comment: Thanks, Matt!  I guess it comes down to scoping for me.  You say "two or more messages, even if they contain the same data, ought to have different JMSMessageID values if they constitute different messages within a repository."  To many of us, these are different instances of the same message.  Logically they *are* the same message and their existence as separate physical copies is a low-level IBM implementation detail we should be shielded from. Will be interesting to see how the JMS group resolves the discrepancy between the test suite and the spec intent as Nigel describes it.