# Preserving MessageID in Pub-sub

Tags: ibm-mq

A message is PUT on an Alias Queue with a Message ID say "M1". There is a Topic on which this message is posted by the Alias Queue. There is a subscription which takes the message from the Topic and puts on a local Queue. The Message ID on the local queue is no M1. It is a string of bytes. Also the correlation ID of the message is not M1.

Is it possible to retain the original Message ID of the message that was dropped on the Alias Queue in any of the header fields of the message on the target queue?

Comment: MQ doesnt preserve the message id across pubsub.  Please refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001655/should-the-jmsmessageid-change-between-publish-and-subscribe

Comment: SO isn't a forum and thus there are no "threads" here.  However, Umapathy is correct that this is a dupe. Also, please see SO's question guidelines [concerning signature lines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).